# How can I prevent page jumping to bottom upon click after logging out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

This issue is only happening on Chrome. On the log in page, on the first mouse click anywhere on the page or keyboard key pressed the page jumps to the bottom. The first time you visit the login page and click and/or log in this does not happen. Only after you have logged in once before and log out will this occur and only in the Chrome browser.

**EDIT:** Chrome needs to save the login username. After log out if you click in the username input and select the username you logged in with before the page will jump to the bottom. Either this way or if you use the "save username and password" option for this site will the issue be reproduced.

After the first click it wont jump again unless you refresh the page and then click. This only happens on this one page and I cannot figure out why it is happening nor any solution to fix the issue. Chrome does autofill the username and password information in after the first log in which may or may not be the issue however other browsers do not display this jumping behavior regardless.
I have set up a temp account for anyone willing to help me and have a look. I would reproduce the issue here if possible but I do not know the cause or solution.
The page is https://winningsportsplays.com/britneydeluca/login 
Login user name: tempuser 
Temp Password: tempuser22 
Will gladly rephrase and reproduce the issue here once I know what it is.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. macOS 10.12, Chrome 62

Comment: same can't reproduce this issue

Comment: Using macOS 10.11.6 Chrome Version 75.0.3770.142

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. You may want to give a step by step on how you are getting the error to reproduce.

Comment: @Brad I have added an EDIT to further explain.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce what you described and using the chrome debugger I pointed the source of it to recaptcha__en.js, which is loaded from google. Doing a Quick [google search](https://www.google.com/search?ei=EwgyXczgKsTH_Qbl9pk4&q=recaptcha%20jump%20to%20bottom&oq=recaptcha%20jump%20to%20bottom&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i22i29i30.146322.146709..146923...0.0..0.80.212.3......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i22i30.acBAtD_yP3M&ved=0ahUKEwiMtvrdysHjAhXEY98KHWV7BgcQ4dUDCAo&uact=5) this seems like a common bug, specially in IOS.

Comment: I read some of the posts on the google search but it doesn't relate to the issue I'm having. There is no reCaptcha to solve. The page jumps when you reselect a saved username in the input field or have already had Chrome save the info on first login.

Comment: From what I experienced, the page jumps on any click on any part of the body, it isn’t related to interacting with the input

Comment: Yes this is true only if you tell Chrome to save your login the first time, log out, and then try to log in again this will occur in my experience as well.